# Send notification when answer is posted

Tags: 7, notifications, message-subscribe

I use [message_notify](http://drupal.org/project/message_notify) with drupal commons. One of the preset messages is commons_q_a_question_answered. I tried to send this message via rules module without success (action "Send message with Message notify") and using the example module with a php custom action, no success too.

Do you have the same problem ? do you solve it ?

I reported a bug in the module [here](https://drupal.org/node/2085497)

Comment: I using https://drupal.org/project/notify to send email, when new content is created.

Comment: maybe I have to mention I am using drupal 7.x branch

Comment: I also noticed that when an user is following a question he receives a notification when he add an answer but not the other followers.

Comment: Can you add a copy (in rules export format) of your rule that doesn't seem to work? That should help (a lot) to understand your question ... and probably result in one or more answers also ...

Comment: Seems to be a server issue.